# About a set theory using Extensionality, Foundation, Limitation of Size and the Grothendieck universe axiom

Tags: set-theory

Building upon the classical first order logic with equality, let T be the set theory given, using the language of NBG, by the following axioms:
1: Class extensionality
2: Foundation
3: The existence of a class-function bijective between the proper class On of ordinals and the proper class universal V of all sets
4: The existence of a proper class of Grothendieck universes.

From 2 and 3, we get the existence of a setlike well-order on every class (including V), giving also global choice, the fact that any two proper classes are bijective, giving also replacement (so, also Separation and the existence of the empty set). Moreover Azriel Lévy showed that 3 and the axiom of Power sets gives the axiom of Union.
From 4 and the axiom of Union, we get the Power set axiom (and, also the axiom of Pairs) and the axiom of infinity. We also have a proper class of strong inaccessibles. So that T seems at least as strong than NBG (including Foundation and Global choice) + the existence of a proper class of inaccessibles.
Did somebody develop such a theory ?
Specially, how in such a linear development of T could we avoid a vicious circle concerning the axiom of Union ?

Comment: Your theory doesn't have any comprehension or separation principles?

Comment: As Limitation of Size entails replacement, separation is available as a consequence of Extensionality and Limitation of size

Comment: I don't see LS on your list. You seem to claim that you get LS from 2, and 3, but this is not true. For example, take the ordinals only from any ZFC model, with all definable classes. This will satisfy 1, 2, 3, but neither LS nor separation.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that I could get from 2 and 3 that two proper classes are always in bijection, because a class A is proper iff given a bijective F: V --> On and the inclusion  I of A in V, we have that FoI(A) is a cofinal class of ordinals.

Comment: Suppose that the only sets there are are ordinals, so we can have 1, 2, and 3 being true. The class of limit ordinals below $\omega^\omega$ is definable, but it is not an ordinal, hence not a "set" in the universe I am describing. So it is a proper class in this model, but not bijective with all ordinals. So LS fails in this model. Also separation, pairing, etc.

Comment: So that every proper class is in bijection with a proper (and so cofinal) class of ordinals, when two cofinal classes of ordinals must be in bijection.

Comment: Finally, I must change 3 to 3 bis in order to have full Limitation of Size, with:

Comment: 3 bis: Two proper classes are always bijective

Comment: That is exactly what I understand LS to say: all proper classes are equinumerous.